# Checking if string starts with _ or a number (0-9)

Tags: java, regex, string

My code parses an XML file to look for IDs. But I only need to store the ones starting with `_` or some number.

```
Node legacyNode = (Node) xPath2.evaluate(elem, XPathConstants.NODE);
Element legacyElem = (Element) legacyNode;
if (legacyElem != null) {
  String legacyId = legacyNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
  if (legacyId.matches("_(.*)")) {
    entry.setLegacyID(legacyId);
  }
}
```

`if (legacyId.matches("_(.*)"))`  checks for IDs starting with `_`. I don't know what I should change it to, so it checks for numbers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the regular expression `[_0-9](.*)` instead of `_(.*)`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
 legacyId.matches("^[_0-9].*$")
```

Comment: No need to add the `^` and `$` anchors, `matches()` does it automatically.

Comment: @sp00m: Yes I am aware but as a habit I just use it. I guess there is no harm in being verbose and it is a good practice once someone translates this into `Pattern.compile` call.

Comment: *`Matcher.find` call ;) But I agree that it's sometimes more readable to re-specify those anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just substring and compare?:

```
String sample = /*whatever*/;
String check = sample.substring(0, 1);
if (check.matches("[0-9_]")) {
    // starts with number or _
}
```

Edit based on the comment's suggestion below:

```
String sample = /*whatever*/;
String check = sample.substring(0, 1);
if ("_1234567890".indexOf(check) != -1) {
    // starts with number or _
}
```

Do note you should check that the string isn't empty/null to start

Comment: If you use substring, then use it till the end: `"0123456789_".indexOf(check) != -1` No need for matches :)

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the logic into the XPath expression? This may not be faster, but under certain circumstances it may be more elegant.